# How to save the URL of anonymous user on a webform?

Tags: webforms, cookies

Using Webform 7.x-3.18, I'd like to save the referring URL of an anonymous visitor on a webform. I added some code to MYTHEME__preprocess_page() in template.php to save the info as a cookie:
user_cookie_save(array('webform_referrer' => $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']));

On my webform I added a hidden component, with a default value of %cookie[Drupal_visitor_webform_referrer].

I'm testing with safari/chrome/ff on a Mac and on Windows. I can get this to work on my local testserver, but only about 10% of the time on the production server, and never from Windows to the production server. The production server has hardware load balancing. I'm suspecting this is a caching issue. I've also read that server vars may not be available as webform default values for anon users (http://drupal.org/node/296453#comment-2397674) - is this the issue? Why then would it be working for anon users coming to my local server?

I can't think of another way to integrate this easily into webform as a hidden field. Perhaps I have to write some kind of custom hander to save the referrer?

Comment: Have you tried  %server[HTTP_REFERER] as default value for your webform's hidden field?

Comment: That won't work, because the value is recorded when the webform is submitted. And when it is submitted, the referring page is contact-us, so we would never see the real referring page. That's why I'm capturing the original referrer in a cookie. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

So you can achieve this using form alter,

create a text field namely 'refer_url' for saving referring url, then using following snippet in your module you can save the referring url. You can hide this field in display using css or form alter.

```
function module_name_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_27') { 
    $form['submitted']['refer_url']['#default_value'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Same problem - when the page is first loaded, the default value is correctly set. I set a breakpoint in my form_alter. When the form is submitted, I reach it again, and this time the referrer is set to the webform, not the site I was coming from. That's why I tried using a cookie to save the value and stash it.

Comment: Are you tried this with textfield, i got it working perfectly. However it is the same case as you said for the hiddenfield. Try with textfield and just hide it using css in frontend